# Defining 32 bits integer in Fortran 90

Tags: gcc, fortran, gfortran

I am trying to define a derived type which will store 32 bits integers.

I have tried:

```
type myType 
    integer*4 :: high           
    integer*4 :: low            
    integer*4 :: flags
end type
type(myType) :: myVar
```

But when I try to do this:

```
myVar%flags = x'80000000'
```

I get:

```
Error: Arithmetic overflow converting INTEGER(16) to INTEGER(4) at (1). This check can be disabled with the option '-fno-range-check'
```

I am using gfortran (gcc8) in a 64 bits FreeBSD12 installation.